# Update React Hooks State During Render Using useMemo

Tags: reactjs, render, react-hooks, memoization

Can `useMemo` be used *just* to avoid extra referential equality checking code/vars when setting state *during* a render?

Example: `useMemo` with a `setState` during render taken from this [rare documented use case](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-getderivedstatefromprops):

```js
function ScrollView({row}) {
  let [isScrolling, setIsScrolling] = useState(false);

  const lessCodeThanCheckingPrevRow = useMemo(
    () => {
      // Row changed since last render. Update isScrolling.
      setIsScrolling(true); // let's assume the simplest case where prevState isn't needed here
    },
    [row]
  );

  return `Scrolling down: ${isScrolling}`;
}
```

Above drastically reduces code and extra vars, only otherwise used for equality checks, so why do the docs imply referential equality checks should be done manually?

Comment: Very good question. As this would also be directly calling `setIsScrolling` during render it should have the same effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be an elegant way to reduce boiler plate to me. I created a codesandbox to validate its behaviour.

```
const UnitUnderTest = ({prop}) => {
  let [someState, setSomeState] = useState(false);

  const lessCodeThanCheckingPrevRow = useMemo(
    () => setSomeState(current => !current), 
    [prop],
  );

  useEffect(() => console.log('update finished'), [prop])

  console.log('run component');

  return `State: ${someState}`;
}

const App = () => {
  const [prop, setProp] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => setProp(current => !current);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick} >change prop</button>
      <UnitUnderTest prop={prop} />
    </div>
  )
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit recursing-hopper-4ynjm]

Output when clicking the button to change the prop passed to the component:

```
> run component 
> run component 
> update finished
```

As you can see the component has been run twice before the update cycle completed. This is equivalent to the the behaviour of `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

I guess that there is no deeper thought behind why the docs propose a slightly different technique. In a way this is a manual check too but in a neat way. +1 for the idea.

Answer (score 4):

Use the useEffect hook for this behavior. useMemo is used to store a value that might not necessarily change over each renders, so that you avoid useless re-calculation of that value

Comment: Thanks, but `useEffect` runs only after a render, not _during_.

Comment: `useEffect` would be the equivalent to `componentDidUpdate` which runs after a completed render, whereas the solution proposed will immediately re-run the component which is the equivalent to `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

Answer (score 1):

if the problem is having a value that changes on every user action which in this case is scrolling, then useMemo is not the best way to go. Perhaps useCallback is a better option. The code block would be the same as you have defined it above, but instead of useMemo, useCallback, and include the state in the dependency array.